# How extract parts of string, based on pattern using javascript/nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Ex:

```
"Hi, my name is Rafael and I live in Brazil."
```

I need to get, the name of person and the your country, using approach of **express**, for example:

```
"Hi, my name is %name% and i live in %country%"
```

Exists, some tool, to do this?

Comment: Regex is one way. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe,

```
(Hi, my name is )[^\r\n]*( and I live in )[^.\r\n]*.
```

replaced with,

```
$1%name%$2%country%.
```

might be somehow close to what might be desired here, not sure though.

```js
const regex = /(Hi, my name is )[^\r\n]*( and I live in )[^.\r\n]*./g;
const str = `Hi, my name is Rafael and I live in Brazil.`;
const subst = `$1%name%$2%country%.`;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log(result);
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TPOiAI/1/)